# Regular Expression Failing in List

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to find the term *DRFT5.147.001* within a list like that shown below. However my Regex expression isn't returning any results, which seems strange.

List :
    Words:

```
> ['DRFT5.147.001', '0000000000000000', '0139', '10.00',
> '700000031479999', '05/27/13', '(002)', '<MAN.', 'CORR', 'BY', 'LG0',
> 'DRFT5.147.001', '00000000', '0139', '25.00', '70000003147999999',
> '05/27/13', '(002)', '<MAN.', 'CORR', 'BY']
```

Code

```
ii = [i for i,item in enumerate(words) if re.match(r'w{3}d{1}\.d{3}\.d{3}',item)]
```

This code is for words like **DRFT5.147.001** and preferably also for similar words such as  **DRFT5.147.002**

Comment: Is this still related to your removing rows from a DataFrame somehow?

Comment: @JonClements Fortunately Not. :) . Although its the same stream which I am breaking in many parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing to:

```
r'\w{4}\d{1}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}'
```

Generally you have to escape all `.` characters because this has a special meaning in regex. Additionally, when referencing to either digit or word characters you don't simply use the letter, but must let python know that you are referring to something special, hence the `\`

Also DRFT5 has 4 letters and one 1 digit, hence changing to `\w{4}`

Worth mentioning that you don't have to create another pattern to match `DRFT5.147.002`, this regex pattern will match that perfectly.